# проблема с адаптивной версткой.(cо свойством media screen)

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

при верстке экспериментального макета обнаружил что media screen не адаптируется под ширину 400px и блоки как бы становятся не на то пространство которое я указал в css.нужно это исправить.

```css
* {
  transition: all 1s;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: brown;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.content {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
  .main {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
  }
  .content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .main {
    display: flex;
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  .content {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Что за устройства с максимальной шириной 400 и 700?

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .main {
    display: flex;
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  .content {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
  .main {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
  }
  .content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
  }
}
```

Сначала 700 потом 400